# Java threadpools and runnables creating runnables

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, runnable, callable

Bear with me as I'm not terribly savvy in multithreaded programming...

I'm currently building out a system that uses a ThreadPool ExecutorService for various runnables. That much is straightforward. However, I'm looking at the possibility of having the runnables themselves spawn an additional runnable based on what happens in the original runnable (ie, if success, do this, if fail, do this, etc as some tasks must be complete before others execute). It should be noted that the main thread does not need to be notified of the results of these tasks, although it might be handy for handling exceptions, ie, if an external service cannot be contacted and all threads are throwing exceptions as a result, then stop submitting tasks and periodically check on the external service until it comes back up. This isn't completely necessary, but it would be nice.

Ie, submit Task A. Task A does some things. If everything goes well, Task A will execute Task B. If something doesn't work out properly or an exception is thrown, execute Task C. Each child task may also have additional tasks, but only a few levels deep. I'd much rather do something like this than large, snarled conditionals in a single task as this approach allows for much greater flexibility.

However, I'm not certain how this would affect the thread pool. I would assume that any additional thread(s) created from within a thread in the pool would exist outside of the pool as they themselves were not submitted directly to the pool. Is this a correct assumption? If so, it's likely a bad idea (well, if not, it may not be a very good idea anyway) as it could result in a lot more threads as the original thread completes and a new task is submitted while the thread spawned from the earlier task is still going (and may last considerably longer than others).

I've also considered implementing these as Callables instead and placing a response object in the Future that is returned, then add the appropriate Callable to the thread pool based on the response. However, this would tie all actions back to the main thread, which seems an unnecessary bottleneck. I suppose I could place a Runnable into the pool that itself handles the execution of the Callable and subsequent actions, but then I get twice as many threads.

Am I on the right track here or am I completely off the rails?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this, but it can be useful for you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html

Comment: Pretty nifty, but not quite what I'm going for. Breaking the workload into smaller chunks isn't really what's needed, but more a pattern for conditional task chaining within a pool, in a sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you want. You need to be careful you don't end up creating too many threads.

The following is an example, you could make this more efficient with an ExecutorCompletionService and alternatively you could use Runnable's.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;


public class ThreadsMakeThreads {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadsMakeThreads().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        //Create resources
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int numberOfThreads = 5;

        //Prepare threads
        ArrayList<Leader> leaders = new ArrayList<Leader>();
        for(int i=0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
            leaders.add(new Leader(threadPool, random));
        }

        //Get the results
        try {
            List<Future<Integer>> results = threadPool.invokeAll(leaders);
            for(Future<Integer> result : results) {
                System.out.println("Result is " + result.get());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        threadPool.shutdown();

    }

    class Leader implements Callable<Integer> {

        private ExecutorService threadPool;
        private Random random;

        public Leader(ExecutorService threadPool, Random random) {
            this.threadPool = threadPool;
            this.random = random;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            int numberOfWorkers = random.nextInt(10);
            ArrayList<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<Worker>();
            for(int i=0; i < numberOfWorkers; i++) {
                workers.add(new Worker(random));
            }
            List<Future<Integer>> tasks = threadPool.invokeAll(workers);
            int result = 0;
            for(Future<Integer> task : tasks) {
                result += task.get();
            }
            return result;
        }

    }

    class Worker implements Callable<Integer> {

        private Random random;

        public Worker(Random random) {
            this.random = random;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            return random.nextInt(100);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Submitting tasks to the thread pool from other tasks is quite meaningful idea. But I am afraid you think of running new tasks on separate threads, that really can eat all the memory. Just set a limit to the number of threads when the pool is created, and submit new tasks to that thread pool.

This approach can be further elaborated in different directions. First, treat tasks as ordinary objects, with interface methods, and let that methods decide if they want to submit this object to the thread pool. This requires that each task knows its thread pool - pass it as a parameter at the time of creation. Even more convenient, keep reference to the thread pool as a thread local variable.

You can easily emulate functional programming: an object represents a function call, and for each parameter it has corresponding set method. When all parameters are set, the object is submitted to the thread pool.

Another direction is actor programming: task class has single set method, but it can be called multiple times, and if previous argument is not yet processed, the set method does not submit the task to the thread pool, but simply stores its argument in a queue. The run() method processes all available arguments from the queue and then returns.

All this features are implemented in the dataflow library https://github.com/rfqu/df4j. I wrote it intentionally to support task-based parallelism.

Comment: Task which is executed directly within another task is not a task, it is just a method. Reword your question so that task means a piece of work for thread pool (Runnable or Callable), then, probably, I could understand what you want.